# iframe with local html on React or Angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, iframe, aws-amplify, src

**I'm trying to show a local html file in an iframe.**
In both Angular and React, It works on development mode, **but on production** (AWS Amplify) **I get the error "cannot match any routes".**

I tried all the answers on previous similar questions but no solution for me.
I tried many sorts of locations( in src, in public, creating assets folder etc ).
I tried many sorts of address syntax such as:

```
<iframe src="address.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="./address.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="../address.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="./assets/address.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="../assets/address.html"></iframe>
<iframe src={process.env.BASE_URL + "/assets/address.html"}></iframe>
<iframe src="https://awsAmplifyAddress.com/assets/address.html"></iframe>
```

etc...

**Help...**

Answer (score 2):

Please read the below question first answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

you have implemented the **catch-all strategy** in which all the requests to the server respond **index.html** which again starts rendering your app and app try to find address.html page your app route which doesn't exist in your app.

Answer (score 1):

**Abishek**, you saved me so much time. Thank you so much!
I completely forgot about the single page routing issue.
So the solution for me was to:

1. Go to AWS Amplify console
2. Go to Rewrites and Redirects
3. Add html to the source address which is for redirecting files.

See the added image
[image: Html is added]